# C++ char* to LPWSTR for CreateProcess without success

Tags: c++, type-conversion, createprocess

I'm trying to recast a char* to a LPWSTR to use in the CreateProcess API-function. However, I can't get it to work properly. (Compiler is not complaining in the end, however CreateProcess keeps telling me it can't find the path specified (error-code)). This makes me assume that recasting the char* into a LPWSTR fails and therefore, the path is not accessible. (I also tried it with functions such as `mbstowcs`, but without any luck so far.

My sample-code:

```
int StartCommand(char* Command) {
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    cout << Command << endl; //Shows the right command

    wchar_t wtext[20];
    mbstowcs(wtext, Command, strlen(Command) + 1);//Plus null
    LPWSTR CommandLPWSTR = wtext;

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, CommandLPWSTR, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW | CREATE_SUSPENDED | CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;
        cout << GetLastErrorAsString() << endl; //TELLS ME: Can't find the path specified
        Message = "Couldn't start command!";
        Exit(Message);
        }
    AssignProcessToJobObject(Handle, pi.hProcess); // Does not work if without CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB
    ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    return pi.dwProcessId;
    }

Pid = StartCommand((char*)("C:/notepad.exe").c_str());
```

Comment: simply cast  `char*` to a `LPWSTR` of course absolute senseless. need pass correct unicode (wide char) string to `CreateProcessW` or use `char*` with `CreateProcessA` and are you copy notepad to `C:/notepad.exe` ?

Comment: `(char*)("C:/notepad.exe").c_str()` This can't possibly compile. The code you show is not the code you run. Also, there's normally no file named `notepad.exe` in the root of `C:\ ` drive. What makes you think `CreateProcess` doesn't tell you the truth?

Comment: You can still use `CreateProcessA` which accepts `const char *`. Though it exists for compatibility.

Comment: C:\notepad.exe is the right location. When I execute the command in my cmd manually, it pops up notepad right away. Actually the above does compile, but `notepad.exe` is replaced by a concatenation of a string and a constant. When I use `CreateProcessA`, I get problems with the 9th parameter (`&si`)?